# Getting full path of file in COCOS2D-X on Android devices

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am trying to obtain an XML file in my project but I can't seem make work right. 
I am using `libXML` (the one that comes with cocos2d-x-2.0.4) to parse XML files.

I'm using `CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils() -> fullPathFromRelativePath( );` but the problem is, for Android versions, it will not give the full path. It works fine on iOS, though.

I then looked at the GitHub and saw something weird. It turns out that `fullPathFromRelativePath( )` will only **return whatever you pass onto it**.

From the [GitHub](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/gles20/cocos2dx/platform/android/CCFileUtils.cpp):

```
const char* CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath(const char *pszRelativePath)
{
    return pszRelativePath;
}
```

I've looked everywhere and all I get is how to read XML files using `CCFileUtils`. I am already able to parse XML files. The only issue is that I can't get the full path of the XML file using `fullPathFromRelativePath()` in Android.

How can I get the full path of the XML file in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that function. The problem is that your xml files are inside apk, which is a zipped file, you cannot read that file directly, you should use something like

```
long tmpSize;
const char* xmlData = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE, "r", &tmpSize);
```

then you can use lib xml to handle the data you get.

but remember you cannot modify anything inside apk file. if you want to write to xml, you need to copy it to some writable path first (like `sdcard` or using `getWritablePath()`).

For the files not inside apk, you can use fopen() directly, you do not need getFileData() any more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning to use `getFileData()` instead if I didn't get any luck getting the file path. Guess it was the right answer all along.